"Both our houses are big"
"Both our houses are big " whether it mean 1.They each have one house.
2.Collectively they are co-owner of two houses
3.They both have two houses/four in total
–i think only number 2 is correct.

'Both' means 'each one of two'.  The sentence 'Both our houses are big' says that each of two houses are big, but is not precise about the ownership. Both 1 and 2 could be correct; 3 is an error.

Context? If they are two neighbours it means that each person has one large house. It would require context to understand whether each person owned two homes.  If they are a couple who are into renting property, then they could be the co-owners of two individual buildings.  This question lacks... dare I say it? Context? Despite what some users might say, answering contextless questions is not always answerable.

It is so lacking in meaning that if (3) were the situation, any native speaker would say or write something like 'Between us we own four big houses'.

@Mari-LouA. Two friends are married and each has one beautiful wife. Third friend says "Both your wives are beautiful"/,your both wives are beautiful will this sentence be correct referring to each wife of his two friends or two wives of each friend –

@MichaelHarvey. Two friends are married and each has one beautiful wife. Third friend says "Both your wives are beautiful"/,your both wives are beautiful will this sentence be correct referring to each wife of his two friends or two wives of each friend –

In a nation where the law permits polygamy, the statement might be ambiguous. Not in mine. Also the friends whom he is addressing know how many wives they have. Language and common sense are intimately linked.

@Micheal Harvey but in countries where polygamy is not permitted then i believe these given sentences is reffering to each wife of his both friends. Am i correct

@MichaelHarvey Without any further context I would always interpret the sentence as 1 being the most likely scenario. Occam's razor.

You can't say your both wives.

Bilal Zafar - if the third friend says "Both your wives are beautiful" to his two friends, each of them (unless they are mad) will know exactly how many wives he has, and thus what the third friend means. Language is used in the real world by real people who know things.

@KateBunting. are "Your Both" and "Both your" not same as in "Your both houses" "Both your houses" " Your both wives" "Both your wives"?

You can't say your both houses either. Both has to come first.

1. or 2.
There are two houses: “Both … houses …”
They are owned by us: “… our houses …”
It could mean that I own one and you own the other, or it could mean the we own both of them together.
